# Blocking domains / IP addresses in answers?

Tags: discussion, support

We get a few spammers on travel.SE - mainly obscure travel companies and travel websites hoping for linkbait, I guess.

However one in particular has created a couple of accounts and posted useless answers a few times, despite suspensions - they start again when the suspensions end.  They're suspended again (for longer) at present, but given they started again IMMEDIATELY, I don't see them improving.

Is it possible to block domains, or because you might get someone spamming a site which isn't theirs which would be problematic, block IP addresses? (all their accounts are on the same IP so far).

I envisage problems with banning IP addresses though...for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Don't suspend spammers, suspension notify all other moderators of the site and the whole community team at SE. That is just unnecessary paperwork for a throwaway account, just destroy spammer accounts that don't contain any useful content.

There is a blacklist for post content that can be used to block URLs, just ping a community team member in chat or write them a mail to get this done (some links to examples of the spam help a lot). There are also IP blocks, but they are used rarely. But if you notice a spammer always spamming from the same IP and don't see any other users from there, you can ask the community team about it.

Comment: What's frustrating is that their first ever answer was a useful use of their site - a genuine answer with a useful link on their travel website.  Since then however, it's all been downhill.  Thanks though, if they come back I'll hop in TL and ask a community team member.